# Nginx proxy cache working for curl, but not browsers

Tags: caching, curl, nginx

I have configured Nginx caching, working primarily off of [Nginx's own documentation](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/). When I call a URL that should be cached using `curl`, it works exactly as expected: a `MISS` on first request, and a `HIT` on all subsequent requests. However, when I call that same URL in any major browser, I get a `MISS` every time - even if that same URL has just been called by `curl` and is cached.

Here is my Nginx config:

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=lb_cache:10m inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;
proxy_cache_key "$request_method$host$request_uri";

proxy_cache_lock on; 
proxy_cache_use_stale updating;

server {
    location / {
        proxy_cache lb_cache;

        proxy_ignore_headers Expires;
        proxy_hide_header Expires;

        proxy_cache_valid 200 60m; 
        proxy_cache_revalidate on; 

        proxy_no_cache $no_cache;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_cache_control $http_pragma $cookie_nocache $arg_nocache;

        add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;

        proxy_pass http://webservers;

        if ($request_uri ~* "/(admin/)") {
            set $no_cache true;
        }   
        if ($http_cookie ~* "SESS") {
            set $no_cache true;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I ensure that my cache is consistently being used, and what is it about the browsers that's different from curl when making the request that causes my cache to miss?

Comment: The cause for this is most likely the `proxy_cache_bypass` directive. Check the request headers from your browser for "Cache-Control" or "Pragma". If any of those is present, Nginx will ignore the cache regardless of the header value. My bet is on "Cache-Control".

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, because when I pass one of those headers I see the cache status logged as `BYPASS`. When I just request a page normally, I get `MISS`, even when `curl` is showing a `HIT` status for the same URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be with the `Vary` header that the site was sending. It's running Drupal 7, which apparently was configured to pass the `Vary` header for its own cache busting. Ignoring that header in Nginx resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between curl and a browser is that the browser remembers/caches resources - so a cookie could be responsible (maybe the `if ($http_cookie ~* "SESS") { set $no_cache true; }` part), or a header used in the request by the browser changes the cache usage.

I would compare the exact request made by curl and by the browser in this case - for example with Firebug. That way you can find out what the browser is sending that curl does not send.